# Transmission: Permission Denied EXFAT

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I spent really long time googling this, but I didn't find the answer.
My main account to using this server is called *admin*.
I'm mounting my hdd (formatted in exfat) via **fstab**.

UUID=5AAC-E163   /home/admin/films   exfat   defaults,users,uid=admin,gid=admin  0   0

my start of /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon (I changed only the user part)

NAME=transmission-daemon
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
USER=admin
STOP_TIMEOUT=30

strange is that can't change chown of /home/admin/films even with root.

sudo chown debian-transmission:debian-trasmission /home/admin/films

It writes to me: Operation not permitted

And finally, my question, why on earth every time when i add torrent it writes to me that permission was denied.

Comment: Please add to your question how you run `chown` (your complete input) and the error message.

Comment: `chown debian-transmission:debian-trasmission` is "debian-trasmission" correct?

Comment: Can you find some related messages in the journal, e.g. with `journalctl -ex`? Please give us the output of `apt list exfat*` and `findmnt -t exfat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i finally found out the solution. It is based on a fact that user permissions do not work in exfat. to be clear, you can't change permissions after you mount, so how you mount, it that will remain to the future.

---

Solution is add **umask=0000** in settings when mounting, in my case in fstab.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

If you mounted your partition as a specific user instead of root, here is a slightly more proper solution to run transmission as the same user you mounted your partition as.

For systemd, here how you should to it:

`sudo systemctl edit transmission-daemon.service`

Then add:

```
[Service]
User=your_username
```

You will also have to copy your transmission config to your user folder:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/transmission-daemon/
sudo cp /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json ~/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
sudo chown $USER ~/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

Then reload configs and restart transmissions:

```sh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart transmission-daemon
```